# image check function in one of the checking step always return true

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read some articles and at this resource also, and cann't resolve the problem. My function check images correctly only by size and type, but by resolution it always return true. This function is a part of form validation. Please help me whith my code. Thanks a lot.

Update. The objToCheck is an argument of function:

```js
const objToCheck = {
          obj: value,
          type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'],
          size: 5 * 1024,
          height: 70,
          width: 70,
        };
```

value is a objectFile from inputChangeHandler  event.currentTarget.files[0]

```js
const checkUploadImage = objToCheck => {
  const { obj, type, size, height, width } = objToCheck;
  let result = false;

  if (obj.size <= size * 1024) {
    if (type.includes(obj.type)) {
      let img = new Image();
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(obj);
      if (
        (img.onload = () => {
          let actualHeight = img.height;
          let actualWidth = img.width;
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
          // console.log(actualHeight + ' * ' + actualWidth);
          // console.log(actualHeight >= height && actualWidth >= width);
          return actualHeight >= height && actualWidth >= width;
        })
      ) {
        result = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};

export default checkUploadImage;
```

Comment: Try to print `obj` and `obj.size`. You may get a lead.

Comment: what is obj here, because if it is file object then there is no property which name is `obj`.

Comment: @Dinesh obj >> [object File] obj.size >> 168612.

Comment: @MohitSharma yes. obj here is a objectFile which is come from input. After type chek (2-nd condition) when it returned true, i create a new Image from object. And commented console printed realy width and heigt, and second console print right answer (true or false). But if this: "actualHeight >= height && actualWidth >= width" return false (not in console), variable result still true.

Comment: @MohitSharma arguments are: obj - objectFile ( from input), type - array of allowed filetypes, size - allowed file size(in kb), height and width - allowed height and width of uploading file

Comment: @VolodymyrTabashnyuk upload you `objToCheck` value in question so community can see where you done mistake.

Comment: @VolodymyrTabashnyuk why you need to create `let img = new Image();`

Comment: @MohitSharma updated my question. I create let img = new Image(), because i need to create a image from objectFile, to take resolution from it, because objectFile hasn't width/height properties, but image has them.

Comment: @VolodymyrTabashnyuk, as you have defined condition as `obj.size <= size * 1024` and the value of size is 5 * 1024. So the condition iwll become `obj.size <= 5 * 1024 * 1024` which is far bigger than 168612. I think this may be the problem.

Comment: @Dinesh. No, with size there was no problem. Problem was with resolution. And it was solved in answer I Ineed to use Promise, like Mohit recomended

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong in if condition not good way to check for `onload` event as condition check.
you have to wait for image to load so you can check width and height.
so i suggest you to use `promise`

```js
const checkUploadImage = (objToCheck) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { obj, type, size, height, width } = objToCheck;
    if (obj?.size <= size * 1024) {
      if (type.includes(obj.type)) {
        let img = new Image();
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(obj);
        img.onload = () => {
          let actualHeight = img.height;
          let actualWidth = img.width;
          window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
          console.log(actualHeight + ' * ' + actualWidth);
          console.log(actualHeight, height , actualWidth , width);
          const result = actualHeight >= height && actualWidth >= width;
          resolve(result);
        }
        img.onerror = reject;
      } else {
        resolve(false)
      }
    } else {
      resolve(false)
    }
  })
};

const imageChange = (event) => {
  const check = checkUploadImage({
    obj: event.target.files[0],
    type: ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'],
    size: 1024,
    height: 70,
    width: 70,
  }).then(res => {
    console.log('res', res);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log('err', err);
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    #editable {
      width: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="file" onChange="imageChange(event)"/>
</body>
</html>
```